# VB6/C++ WINAPI to C#

Tags: c#, c++, vb6-migration

I'm working with some hardware which has a DLL. I believe it has two methods of calling the functionality (from using a DLL spy app).

It currently works in VB6 using

```
Public Type Versions
   Pname As Long
   Manuf As Long
   VMajor As Long
   VMinor As Long
   VState As Long
End Type

Public Declare Function FLASH_GetVersion Lib "C:\flash_cntrl.dll" (ByVal fxc_Versions As Long) As Integer

Dim vVers As Versions
Dim strProdName As String
Dim strManuf As String

strProdName = "                                                                                              "
strManuf = "                                                                                              "

vVers.Manuf = StrPtr(strManuf)
vVers.Pname = StrPtr(strProdName)

iReturn = FLASH_GetVersion(VarPtr(vVers))
```

I'm being "forced" to move to C# 2008/2010 to be able to use some other hardware which isn't supported in VB6.

So, I'm trying to use the above and running into the `AccessViolationException` error. I'm "lucky" enough to have a C++ header file with the WinAPI definitions but still struggling. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 typedef struct {
 LPWSTR productname;
 LPWSTR manufacturer;
 unsigned Vers_Major;
 unsigned Vers_Minor;
 unsigned Vers_State;      // = 0 released, > 0 internal use only
} FLASH_INFO;

int WINAPI FLASH_GetVersion  (FLASH_INFO *fxc_Version);
```

My C# so far is

```
static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("C:\\flash_cntrl.dll")]
    public static extern short FLASH_GetVersion(FLASH_INFO vVers);
}

public class FLASH_INFO
{
    public string productname;
    public string manufacturer;
    public int Vers_Major;
    public int Vers_Minor;
    public int Vers_State;
}

        FLASH_INFO vers = new FLASH_INFO();

        string strManuf = "                                ";
        string strProdName = "                                ";

        vers.productname = strProdName;
        vers.manufacturer = strManuf;
        vers.Vers_Major = 0;
        vers.Vers_Minor = 0;
        vers.Vers_State = 0;

        short sRet = NativeMethods.FLASH_GetVersion(vers);

        Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", "sRet", sRet.ToString());
```

It's probably something simple, but I'm relatively new to the C# language (done some desktop programming and silverlight only).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default marshaling for strings is as 8-bit characters, LPWSTR is a Unicode string though.  The return type isn't correct either.  Fix:

```
[DllImport("C:\\flash_cntrl.dll")]
public static extern int FLASH_GetVersion(ref FLASH_INFO vVers);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)
public struct FLASH_INFO
{
    public string productname;
    public string manufacturer;
    public int Vers_Major;
    public int Vers_Minor;
    public int Vers_State;
}
```

Comment: I can't vote as I don't have the reputation, but you deserve it!

Answer (score 0):

string strManuf = "                                "; 
    string strProdName = "                                ";

```
vers.productname = strProdName; 
vers.manufacturer = strManuf;
```

the problem is in those lines. the c++ struct type of them is LPWSTR which translates to IntPtr in .net which is a pointer to an object.

Comment: I understand that. So any idea how I get around that?

Comment: yeah well you could have asked this question without the negative meaningless vote. solve it on your own buddy.

Comment: I didn't negative you as far as I know. I'm not even logged in. But thanks anyway! :)

Comment: i thought you did. it must be someone clicking around. no problem

Comment: It seems it was me who gave the negative feedback however it was accidental. Apparently my vote is locked in now as I pressed it 7 hours ago by mistake. Sorry about that, looks like I inadvertantly almost caused a riot!